# jQuery clone div on double click and change style on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to clone `selected` div. On single click it should give a border to clicked div. On double click it should clone that div.

When I click it is not giving border outline to the selected div. On double click it should clone that div, that's all.

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/xpvt214o/842603/):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    
        $("div").on('click', function(){
                alert("clicked Div is cloned!!!");
            });
            
            $(div).addClass("selected"); 
            
            $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
});
    });
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  
  <div class="col-md-12 context_image">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/ferrari/ferrari_PNG10680.png" class="imgsen-117 sim-row-edit">
  </div>
  
  <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt20-l">Why is building with Variant so darn fun and dead-easy?
  </div>
  
  <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-12 smalltxt context_menu context_link"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btntst-b">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

I would rather not give any class to div's as I have many of them in my code.

Comment: Which div you want to clone?

Comment: the one i clicked, clciked div should be surrounded by a border line, on double clicking it, that div should be cloned

Comment: You can use like `$(this).clone().appendTo('#clone-wrapper-div-id');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(document).on('click', "div", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked Div is cloned!!!");
        $("div.selected").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });

    $( "div" ).dblclick(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var clonned = $(this).clone();
            clonned.removeClass('selected');
            clonned.insertAfter($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the out most div is not getting selected no matter where ever i click, how shall i clone all of it

Comment: @user2828442 This is because the inner divs override the outermost div. If you add some padding to it, then you can view the outermost div.
Check my updated fiddle for example. https://jsfiddle.net/codething/uh6eg7y2/2/

Comment: @user2828442 Added border to outermost div just to clearify the difference.

Comment: i am trying to achieve the same on right click, i am trying with `$(document).on("contextmenu","div", function(event) {`   and then `$("div.selected").addClass('selecteddiv');`  , is this the right way ?

Comment: @user2828442 Yes, that's right. Copy the code which we created for click and just relace the click with `contextmenu`

Comment: i tried, here is the fiddle, its not working, can you please have a look - http://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/xpvt214o/843425/

Comment: if you can check out this fiddle, right click menu not opening  ,  on right click open menu and click clone to clone the selected div - http://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/fvensq45/5/

Comment: @user2828442 There are syntax errors in your fiddles. you can check console for more details.
You need to change `e.preventDefault()` to `event.preventDefault()`. And in the second fiddle there is brace closing error.

Comment: clickedElement = $(this);  this is causing problem, how to use something like div.selected , here is updated with color selection on right click and click on clone -jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/g6p2qzhn/7 , you can update this one with the right approach

Answer (score 0):

try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/2uzd83x4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-12").children('div').on('click', function(){
                    $('.selected').removeClass("selected"); 
            $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        });
    $(".col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-12").children('div').on('dblclick', function(){
                let clone = $(this).clone();
          $(this).after(clone);
        });


});
```

Comment: please dont use any specific class like `.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-12` , just want to achieve on clicked div

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that.

You can remove the `e.stopPropagation()` statement if you want any click to a div also register click to wrapping divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on('dblclick', 'div', function(e) {
    $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this));
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

  <div class="col-md-12 context_image">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/ferrari/ferrari_PNG10680.png" class="imgsen-117 sim-row-edit">
  </div>

  <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt20-l">Why is building with Variant so darn fun and dead-easy?
  </div>

  <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 smalltxt context_menu context_link"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btntst-b">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

</div>
```